# GAE structuring models without denormalizing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying restructure a relational database for Google App Engine and I'm having issues with modeling a set of relationships in a way that will let me query the data I need in an efficient manner.

As a contrived example, say I have the following models:

```
class Rental(db.Model):
    # ancestor of one or more RentalDatas
    date = db.DateProperty()
    location = db.IntegerProperty()
    # + customer, etc

class RentalData(db.Model):
    # a Rental is our parent
    unicorn = db.ReferenceProperty(Unicorn, collection_name='rentals')
    mileage_in = db.FloatProperty()
    mileage_out = db.FloatProperty()
    # + returned_fed, etc

class Unicorn(db.Model):
    name = db.StringProperty()
    color = db.IntegerProperty()
    # 'rentals' collection from RentalData
```

Each rental can include multiple unicorns, so I'd rather not combine the `Rental` and `RentalData` models if I can help it. I'll almost always be starting with a given `Unicorn`, and I'd like to be able to query, say, whether the unicorn was returned fed on the last **x** rentals, without having to iterate through every `RentalData` in the unicorn's `rentals` collection and query for the parent, just to get the date to sort on.

Do I just have to bite the bullet and de-normalize? I've tried duplicating `date` in `RentalData`, and using parent() as needed to get the corresponding `Rental` when I need properties from it. It works, but I'm worried I'm just taking the easy way out.

Comment: Have a look at the new NDB datastore for repeated stuctured properties to solve your problem with multiple unicorns.

Comment: I like your example :). But back on topic, have you thought of making the inheritance the other way around? The unicorn has a collection of rental data to make things more efficient.

Comment: @voscausa Are you suggesting a collection of `RentalData` in `Rental`? I still wouldn't be able to query on a `Unicorn` and get only the most recent rentals.

Comment: Yes. But have a look at NDB repeated stuctured properties and NDB queries, to find out if you do the queries you suggest : https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#filtering_structured_properties

Comment: @Linuxios I'm not sure I understand; what relationship would `RentalData` and `Unicorn` have?

Comment: @CarsonMorrow: Unicorn would have a collection of RentalData's